# calculate values from row and column then output to mulltiple cell

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have a table with these columns:

```
1st col          2nd col    3rd col     4th col
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |  1st Inst  |  2nd Inst  |
|   Athletic        |   100 |            |            |
|   Socio-cultural  |   100 |            |            |
|   Library         |   150 |            |            |
|   Medical         |   50  |            |            |
|   School Organ    |   20  |            |            |
|   Dev't Fee       |   100 |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|   Buttons: (ADD) (DEL)    |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |___Input____|___Input____|
------------------------------------------------------
```

the values on the 1st and 2nd column are generated using php from
 the database. this table is a dynamic table wherein the number of the
 columns can increase or decrease by pressing the buttons. and at the bottom
 of the table i have input fields that can also increase as the columns of the 
 table increases.
 what i want is that when i input a value on the input fields, it will 
 be process in a calculation together with the values each row in the 2nd column 
 and that output will be  written on the corresponding row of 
 the 3rd/4th column depending on which input field contains the initial value.

example is like these:

```
1st col          2nd col    3rd col     4th col
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |  1st Inst  |  2nd Inst  |
|   Athletic        |   100 |   200      |            |
|   Socio-cultural  |   200 |   400      |            |
|   Library         |   300 |   600      |            |
|   Medical         |   400 |   800      |            |
|   School Organ    |   500 |   1000     |            |
|   Dev't Fee       |   600 |   1200     |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|   Buttons: (ADD) (DEL)    |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |   2        |            |
```

---

i have no problem in the calculation part...what my problem is how can i output 
 the values on the corresponding columns.

here is the php code for retrieving the values for both 1st and 2nd col.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM miscfeelist');
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($result)){
  foreach ($result as $r){
echo   '<tbody id="tb"><tr>
<td align="center">'.$r['MiscFee_Name'].'</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="value">'.$r['MiscFee_Value'].'</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="dwn">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="dwn">&nbsp;</td>
</tbody></tr>';
    }
  }
else
{
echo "No Record in the Database.";
}
```

here is the input field:

```
 <tr>

    <td  align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td  align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FF9900"><input class="inst" type="text" style="border:thick" size="12" onkeyup="MiscFeeColl()" placeholder="1st" value="0"></td>
    <td  align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FF9900"><input class="inst" type="text" style="border:thick" size="12" onkeyup="MiscFeeColl()" placeholder="2nd" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
```

here is my code for the calculation:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < theOddOnes.length; i++){ //rows
            for(var l = 0; l < res.length; l++){

                inst = theOddOnes[l].value;

                fund165 = (MiscFee/GrandTot()*inst);
                fund165 = +fund165.toFixed(2);

                //columns
                Miscfee123 = (parseFloat(val[l].innerHTML)/MiscFee*fund165);
                Miscfee123 = +Miscfee123.toFixed(2);     

                document.getElementsByClassName("dwn")[l].firstChild.nodeValue = Miscfee123;


            }
        }
```

the output of these calculation is these:

```
1st col          2nd col    3rd col     4th col
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |  1st Inst  |  2nd Inst  |
|   Athletic        |   100 |   200      |      400   |
|   Socio-cultural  |   200 |   600      |      800   |
|   Library         |   300 |   1000     |      1200  |
|   Medical         |   400 |            |            |
|   School Organ    |   500 |            |            |
|   Dev't Fee       |   600 |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|   Buttons: (ADD) (DEL)    |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |___2________|____________|
------------------------------------------------------
```

my code is displaying it horizontally.and i've been working on this for the las two weeks..i cant seem to make it to work..pls help..

**EDITED**

I have tried this one and it make sense somehow but i cant make it work with the  other inputs...

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('billingForm');

        for(var i= 0; i < theOddOnes.length; i++){  //rows
            for(var l = 0; l < res.length; l++){

                inst = theOddOnes[i].value;

                fund165 = (MiscFee/GrandTot()*inst);
                fund165 = +fund165.toFixed(2);

                Miscfee123 = (parseFloat(val[l].innerHTML)/MiscFee*fund165);
                Miscfee123 = +Miscfee123.toFixed(2);     

    //          document.getElementsByClassName("dwn")[l].firstChild.nodeValue = Miscfee123;
                myTable.rows[l].cells[i].innerHTML = Miscfee123;

            }
        }
```

here is the output:

```
  200            2nd col    3rd col     4th col
------------------------------------------------------
|   400             |       |  1st Inst  |  2nd Inst  |
|   600             |   100 |            |            |
|   800             |   200 |            |            |
|   1000            |   300 |            |            |
|   1200            |   400 |            |            |
|   School Organ    |   500 |            |            |
|   Dev't Fee       |   600 |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|   Buttons: (ADD) (DEL)    |            |            |
------------------------------------------------------
|                   |       |   2        |            |
```

---

i tried to edit the code to other index but it outputs 0 values.

```
  for(var i= 2; i < theOddOnes.length; i++){    //rows
  for(var l = 3; l < res.length; l++){
```

here is the output:

```
  1st col            2nd col    3rd col     4th col
 ------------------------------------------------------
 |                  |       |  1st Inst  |  2nd Inst  |
 |  Athletic        |   100 |   0        |            |
 |  Socio-cultural  |   200 |   0        |            |
 |  Library         |   300 |   0        |            |
 |  Medical         |   400 |   0        |            |
 |  School Organ    |   500 |   0        |            |
 |  Dev't Fee       |   600 |   0        |            |
 ------------------------------------------------------
 |  Buttons: (ADD) (DEL)    |            |            |
 ------------------------------------------------------
 |                  |       |   2        |            |
```

---